# Delphi I am trying to check for the position of the Sender but i get inaccessible value. How do i do it correctly?

Tags: image, object, pointers, delphi, delphi-12-athens

I have an Image with the function OnMouseUp and i put an if statement using the Sender
it didnt work with the Sender directly because it told me that It has to be an object which it is but it doesnt care.
This is the func:

```
procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.DraggableImageMouseUp(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  Current:^TImage;
begin
  ActiveDrag.Remove(Sender);
  Current:=Sender.ClassInfo;//here is the problem(it doesnt save the pointer in Current)error in if
  if ((Image12.Position.X)<(Current.Position.X+Current.Width/2)) and ((Current.Position.X+Current.Width/2)<(Image12.Position.X+Image12.Width)) then
  begin
    if ((Image12.Position.Y)<(Current.Position.Y+Current.Height/2)) and ((Current.Position.Y+Current.Height/2)<(Image12.Position.Y+Image12.Height)) then
    begin
        Current.Position.X:=Image12.Position.X;
        Current.Position.Y:=Image12.Position.Y;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I tried declaring Current as a pointer to TImage (^TImage) and also tried to set Current:=^Sender.ClassInfo  but it returned the error: Incompatible types 'Pointer' and 'Char'

Comment: Are you looking for `var Current: TImage; begin Current := Sender as TImage`?

Comment: You need to cast the ``Sender`` object like Andreas showed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `CAST` the Sender `Object` as `TImage` (use IS operator for more security).
Try something like this:

```
var
  Current:TImage;
begin
  ActiveDrag.Remove(Sender);
  if (Current is TImage) then
    Current := TImage(Sender);
...
```

Now you can access to `Current.ClassInfo`, `Current.ClassName`, `Current.ClassType`, etc.

Comment: Thanks it works now. I put Current := TImage(Sender); instead of Current := Sender.ClassInfo;
Thats the only thing i had to change.

Comment: @LuanZekiri: If `Sender` at some point happens to be something other than a `TImage`, a cast like `TImage(Sender)` may cause memory corruption. For instance, you may find that your app incorrectly sends a $360000 invoice the next week instead of the expected $36 invoice. Using `is`, that will never happen; the issue will be detected directly.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand But i use it in the func image mouse up. the func is intended to only be used by images

Comment: Luan: Yes, it will work in 99% of cases, as long as you are a one-dev team, always sleep well, etc. But if you write software for pacemakers or aircraft, you really do need to be 100.00% sure it always works correctly. Writing `(X as Y)` instead of `Y(X)` isn't much more work, and the runtime check only takes a few nanoseconds, which is absolutely nothing compared to the GUI stuff.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand honestly its not my fault if a coworker cant read that is says DraggableImageMouseUp and is only intended for images. i cant make everything idiot proof.

Comment: @LuanZekiri: Strange, because I can do that, at least in this case and in cases similar to this. But I do agree that software today typically is very buggy. People don't really care about quality.